# SignalR:For Client Side,which signalR package,i need to install?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, client, signalr

I  new to SignalR.I am developing a Project using signalR

Service side i am using WCF and SignalR.And for Client Side,i am using ASP.NET MVC 4.

I followed the steps in below website:-

[Getting Started With SignalR and MVC 5](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc)

for my service side,i am installed the package called

**Install-Package  Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR**

And also i am created my owin startup class and SignalR Hub Class in WCF  Service.

Owin StartupClass:-

```
 [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WCF3.Startup))]
 namespace WCF3
  {
    public class Startup
     {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
         {
            app.MapSignalR();
         }
     }
  }
```

SignalR HubClass:-

```
     public class ConvHub : Hub
       {
         public void send(string user)
          {
              Clients.All.broadcastMesage(user);
          }
       }
```

and My WCF Service:-

```
     public class Service1 : IService1
     {
         public string GetValue(string username)
         {
            string name = "username ="+username;
            Console.WriteLine("u=" + name);
            return name;
         }
     }
```

My Service side Configuration is Completed.

But i don't know,which package i need to install for ASP.NET  MVC ,while Considering MVC as separate Client.

Could Anyone Tell me the package name ,need to install in MVC Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install **Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client** to your wcf service.

configure your start up in wcf service

```
 var connection = new HubConnection("{enter your hub url}");
 var myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("ConvHub");


 myHub.Invoke("send", "your username").ContinueWith(task => {
                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There was an error calling send: {0}", task.Exception.GetBaseException());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Send Complete.");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment ahankendi..i will check it and accept your answer soon